# Rendering Backbone view into multiple elements with different configurations

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js, requirejs

I have a html page with 3 jquery-mobile page widgets. Each page widget has the same header with a slightly different configuration for sub links. I want to  create the Header as a BackboneView and render it for each page widget. Each page widget has it's own view as well. The page template looks like this:

```
<body>

    <div id="news" data-role="page">
        <header class="header"></header>
    </div>

    <div id="updates" data-role="page">
        <header class="header"></header>
    </div>

    <div id="stuff" data-role="page">
        <header class="header"></header>
    </div>

</body>
```

The view for the first page, in this case being news view, gets rendered first. This page creates an instance of the header view. The problem arises when working with the header.

**1)** How do I target the header specifically for the first page, "#news header" while keeping it flexible enough for me to call it again with a different set of parameters when I am ready to load the updates page?

**2)** When I'm ready to load the updates page, it will have a different set of configurations that need to target "#updates header". Therefore I don't want to hardcode tagName on the view.

**3)** How do I pass the first instantiated header to the rest of the views? Or am I thinking about this all wrong and should I be extending a base Header view as a template for each of my pages which come baked in with a set of configs?

The only thing that is different between each header is a class name it will attach to an element in the rendered view and a few anchor links it makes for the page. For this, I am trying to reuse the view as much as possible to have a light footprint.

Note: Not sure if it matters but I'm using requirejs. Maybe there is a suggested way to create a View and always have it reused when necessary since requirejs handles modules as singletons?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an overview like appView.js. It will be in charge to render all the subviews.

In appView (you'd need to require your subviews in this super module, HeaderView):

```
initialize: function() {
    this.$news = $('#news');
    this.$updates = $('#updates');
    this.$stuff = $('#stuff');
},

render:function() {
    var newsView = new HeaderView(param1,param2);
    this.$news.append(newsView.render().el);
    // do the same for your other subviews
}
```

In your subviews (lets say NewsView)

```
initialize:function(param1,param2) {
    this.viewclass= param1;
    //set the other things you need here
},

render: function() {
    this.$el.html("my content here..model/template/anything"));
    this.$el.attr('class',this.vewClass);
}
```

Remember that the point is to have an overview creating new SubViews and calling the render(). I hope it helps.

Edit: If you are waiting for some data to load a specific subview, use a promise. If you are waiting for a collection to finish to fetch use something like that

```
collection.fetch(function() {
    success:function(res,model) {
        new subView(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @françois-richard. The example clears up a lot of the fog but I'm still confused on the HeaderView aspect of this. The NewsView alone makes sense but lets say we also have the UpdatesView. Where does the HeaderView get instantiated? I'm guessing it would be in each one of the PageViews so it can be configured to render the right data but how do I configure the HeaderView so that the "el" is for the current view so that the "events" binding works on correct elements. I'm afraid of duplicate triggers binding to elements multiple times with each HeaderView instance. I hope that makes sense

Comment: I updated my example it was a bit unclear.

Basically all your subviews (news,update,stuff) are the same view with different parameters.
So you create one HeaderView then in app you create several instance of this view but with specific parameters (specific to news,updates or stuff)
Hope it helps